# how to get image full path from WP_Post Object?

Tags: images

i want to get image full path so that i can apply it in the src attribute of image element.

what i am getting right now is the image, generated from function:
the_post_thumbnail();
which i can't apply to image element

what i did so far is:

```
            <?php
                $d=get_cat_ID( 'news' );
                $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$d.'&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC' );
                while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                endwhile;
            ?>
```

what i want is; path of image with its name as below:

http://example.com/folder1/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/image.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
 $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full' );

 $img_src = $img[0];
```

refer this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 1):

you can use wp_get_attachment_image_src. Below is small function for it.

`function get_image_src( $post_id = '', $size_img = 'thumbnail' ) {
    if ( $post_id == '' ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), $size_img );
        $image = $image[0];
        if( !$image ) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return $image; 
}`

echo get_image_src(get_the_ID(), 'full');  //full size to get original image src

here get_the_ID() is post id in loop.